# i need sql query for deleting duplicate records from the table

Tags: mysql, sql

----my table-------

```
id       name         company      salary    
---- ------------- --------------  ----------
1        abc            xyz            10000

2        abc             x             10000

3        ab              y             15000

1        abc            xyz            10000

4        bc             yz             1000

3        ab              y             15000

5        ab              xy             15000
```

-----after deleting i need my table like below----

```
id       name         company      salary    
---- ------------- --------------  ----------
1        abc            xyz            10000

2        abc             x             10000

3        ab              y             15000

4        bc             yz             1000

5        ab             xy             15000
```

Comment: Please upload your initial solution and discribe how you tried to address this problem so far. Be specific in naming the obstacles and errors you faced and why you have been unable to make your solution work.

Comment: You have no way of identifying which rows are to be retained. As such, this problem is insoluble.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `table_name` ADD UNIQUE (name,company,salary)**
```

Or you can try below query.

```
DELETE CO
FROM table_name CO
INNER JOIN (
SELECT MIN(ID) ID FROM table_name GROUP BY name,company,salary HAVING count(ID) >1
)INNERTABLE
  ON INNERTABLE.ID=CO.ID;
```

Comment: Hi sagar, i want to delete the data , not to alter and please help me

Comment: @HarshavardhanreddyAdulla Yes,it will delete data with duplication...!!
Just tried once

Comment: You can try my updated answer.It will delete older record if duplication is there.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a temp column to have a primary key

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD tmp INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
```

The call delete removing duplicates

```
delete t
from t
inner join t t2 on t.id=t2.id and t.tmp>t2.tmp
```

and then drop the tmp column